# c# how to get html like DOMexplorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, dom

i can get html source in  webbrowser.

but it is different DOM explorer. (F12 on Internet explorer)

why?

there is more html source in DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because view source gets you the data obtained from server. DOM can be modified by client-side JavaScript, creating, downloading, appending new elements etc.